# Add target=“_top” to ink that is inside the fancybox iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a page setup that is accessed through a fancybox iframe. How can a link that is inside the fancybox iframe, load in the parent window of the iframe? So if the user clicks the link, it will reload the page and load the clicked link. How do I add a target="_top" attribute to the all links?

e.g.

```
$("iframe").on("load", function () {
    $("a").each(function() {
      $(this).attr('target', '_top');
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in your child page you have regular links like :

```
<p>This link opens <a href="http://google.com">GOOGLE</a></p>
<p>This link opens <a href="http://jsfiddle.net">JSFIDDLE</a></p>
<p>This link opens <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">STACKOVERFLOW</a></p>
```

You could set the *attribute* `onclick` to each link from within the parent page using the fancybox `afterShow` callback. Then, set `parent.location.assign()` and `$.fancybox.close()` as the `onclick` attribute value.

This is the code for your parent page :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type : "iframe",
        afterShow : function () {
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("a").attr("onclick", "parent.location.assign(this.href);parent.$.fancybox.close();")
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

Now, each link on the iframed page will close fancybox and load the referred URL in the parent (top) page.

**NOTES** :

- We need to pass `this.href` within the `.assign()` method, which corresponds to `href` value of each link.
- We don't need to include jQuery in the child page.
- Working with iframes is subject to the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

See demo : **http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/openURLfromChildPage_13apr14.html**

Comment: thanks for reply. how not to use this code for my class (.ajax-processed)

Comment: @zhe : what do you mean? if you are using the same fancybox code for different type of content, you could set a condition to apply the code to iframe only. Is that what you want?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know English. I use Google translator. I need to open all links in the parent (top) page. Your code does work. But some links open in iframe  [screenshot](https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/preview/5001483950cc7daf7a11d284b6c65728/mpfs/XMO40mJjnGs4oTOWvyHP5ufjnyoGSUJogac5ZzxuoJEUULcNY8NjgG2Rfnlh9sTnZvAxOsGADeX5vCNmpE_4eg%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=20140414221959%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BBpng&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&size=XXL&crop=0)

Comment: @zhe well, add in your question the relevant html/js code of those links, otherwise I cannot guess what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fancybox 3, you will want this slightly altered version:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        type : "iframe",
        onComplete : function () {
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("a").attr("onclick", "parent.location.assign(this.href);parent.$.fancybox.close();")
        }
    });
});
```

Adding this extra answer as this thread is about the only near useful thing that shows up in searches. I felt it was worth updating for the current version of Fancybox.