# Open a Link to another website from within Fancy Box in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Im stumped..... I'm using Fancybox jquery plug in to display some iframes over the top of my page in a lightbox style.... i have it all working but if I try to link to an external website from within the lightbox using the normal `<a href="http://somesite.com/"> somesite </a>` 
I before you suggest it I have tried `target="_blank"`with no luck.
it opens in the lightbox not in the original window, I dont mind if it opens in a new tab or windows I just cant have it opening in the lightbox... has anyone else experienced this before?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23053971/1055987 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that I have understood the scenario here -

1. You have a link that when clicked, opens the content in a fancybox pop-up.
2. This content has some text and within that, it has a `<a href="http://somesite.com/"> somesite </a>` link. You have also tried `target="_blank"`.
3. When this `<a>..</a>` is clicked, it should act like a normal link and open in a browser (new tab or window). But it opens the this link in the fancybox pop-up instead.

If that's the case then I tried it and the link opened in a new tab.

Please clarify the above doubt of mine.

Thanks.

Comment: That's correct, I'm at work at the moment but I'll post some code/screen shots when I get home

Answer (score 0):

Try `target="_parent"` instead of `target="_blank"`

See following example:

```
<a href="http://somesite.com/" target="_parent"> somesite </a>
```